# Enable submit button if 2 selects are populated

Tags: jquery

I have a form with among others this 2 selects :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="yul_log_christmas_serving_id" id="yul_log_christmas_serving_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="">{{ __('# Personnes | Taille') }}</option>
        @foreach($yul_log_christmas_servings as $serving)
            <option style="color:#6c757d" value="{{ $serving->id }}" {{ $party_loaf_serving_id == $serving->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $serving->servings }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="yul_log_christmas_flavor_id" id="yul_log_christmas_flavor_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="">{{ __('Saveur') }}</option>
        @foreach($frozen_flavor as $flavor)
            <option style="color:#6c757d" value="{{ $flavor->id }}">{{ $flavor->flavor }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

This is the submit button:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-sm" id="add-product" disabled>{{ __('Ajouter au Panier') }}</button>
</div>
```

I have coded the following script to make that the #add-product button is only available if the 2 selects are populated:

```
<script>
    // Yul Log
    if($("#form-category-id").val() == 11 ) {       
$('#yul_log_christmas_serving_id','#yul_log_christmas_flavor_id').on('change', function () {
            $('#add-product').prop('disabled', !$(this).val());
        }).trigger('change');
    }
</script>
```

This doesn't work. As soon as the first select is populated the button is enabled.

So I have tried this:

```
<script>
    // Yul Log
    if($("#form-category-id").val() == 11 ) {
        $('[id^=yul_log]').on('change', function () {
            $('#add-product').prop('disabled', !$(this).val());
        }).trigger('change');
    }
</script>
```

Result is the same.

Would appreciate some jQuery expertise, since I am stuck.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the check for the form category id (`if($("#form-category-id").val() == 11 ) {`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to check both of select to disable/enable the button, so you can add the same event to both of select like this :

```
...
$('#yul_log_christmas_serving_id, #yul_log_christmas_flavor_id').on('change', function() {
    selectChanged();
});

function selectChanged() {
    let val1 = $('#yul_log_christmas_serving_id').val();
    let val2 = $('#yul_log_christmas_flavor_id').val();
    $('#add-product').prop('disabled', (val1 === "" || val2 === ""));
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking only for the currently changed `select`. You need to change both:

```
let christmasServing = $('#yul_log_christmas_serving_id');
let christmasFlavor = $('#yul_log_christmas_flavor_id');
$('#yul_log_christmas_serving_id','#yul_log_christmas_flavor_id').on('change', function () {
    $('#add-product').prop('disabled', !(christmasServing.val() && christmasFlavor.val()));
}).trigger('change');
    }
```